# Binary search code fails efficiency check

Tags: c++, performance, search, binary-search

I have been tasked to complete a technical assessment for a position involving a simple C++ coding exercise. The problem was to check if a number exists in a sorted array, where:

- `ints[]` is the array to be sorted
- `size` is the size of the array
- `k` is the number to be checked

The requirement was to implement a solution that uses as few CPU cycles as possible. My solution was as follows:

```cpp
static bool exists(int ints[], int size, int k)
{
    std::vector<int> v(ints,ints+size);

    if (std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), k))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

This failed the performance test with a million items in the array. I am a bit confused as to why. Is it the fact that I am creating a new structure from the vector? Does it involve copying all of the items in a new location in memory?

Comment: What is the big O complexity of your function?

Comment: Vectors always hold values, so yes, it's going to copy everything. In this case you don't need a vector, you can just do `std::binary_search (ints, ints + size, k)`.

Comment: _"Does it involve copying all of the items in a new location in memory?"_ Yes of course it does.

Comment: You are copying N elements for nothing. Why would you do this? You can apply `std::binary_search` to the array given to function arguments.

Comment: *edited* Ah, I get it. I had a few issues with binary search given array was decayed as pointer, and passing by reference somehow threw an error as well. Was a quick-think solution

Comment: The search is O(log(n)). The copy is O(n) ...

Comment: @DariusHente You failed to realize that many of the STL algorithms work with regular old arrays as well as STL containers.  There was no need to create a vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector<int> v(ints,ints+size);` is going to make a copy of your array.  You really don't want to do this in a binary search function since it is an O(N) operation.  That totally dominates the O(logN) of a binary search and makes you algorithm equivalent to a linear search (only worse since you are also consuming O(N) space).  You should be using the array directly in your call to `binary_search` like you do to create the vector with:

```
static bool exists(int ints[], int size, int k)
{
    return std::binary_search(ints, ints+size, k);
}
```